# didSelectRowAtIndex doesn't trigger when pressed on custom cell's text label

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

`didSelectRowAtIndex` doesn't trigger when I press on cell's UITextLabel even though it triggers if I touch on empty area around it.
I have also noticed that this problems occurs only on iPad. On iPhone everything works fine.
I use custom cells designed in IB.
Here is my code:

```
      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            NSString *key = [[self sectionKeys] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
            NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key];
            return [contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

        - (void) viewDidLoad
        {
[super viewDidLoad]
NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *powerKey = @"Power Settings";

[keys addObject:powerKey];

[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cellTwo, cellThree, updatePeriodCell, nil] forKey:powerKey];
[self setSectionKeys:keys];
[self setSectionContents:contents];
        }
```

all my cells are properties.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you check thats the tableView delegate are connected ?

Comment: are you using some custom cell?

Comment: Do you have different Storyboards? They both are connected to your custom UITableViewController?

Comment: Yes, tableView delegates are connected and I use custom cells

Comment: Hm, interesting question. I have experienced a "desynchronization" between cell highlight and `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in the past, and figured it was some bug in iOS. But this is an interesting theory. I would like to see an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was very simple - there was another view above the `UITableView`